# PyQt5: get index of cell widgets and their chosen values

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I am using Python 3.5, and I have a simple code which creates a table with a few combo-boxes inside of it. Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

########################## Create table ##############################
tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 200, 250, 300))
tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
tableWidget.setRowCount(9)
tableWidget.show()

################# Create tablecontent & comboboxes ###################
names = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4']
i = 0
for j in names:
    tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(j))

    comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    combo_option_list = ["Choose...", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
    for t in combo_option_list:
        comboBox.addItem(t)

    tableWidget.setCellWidget(i, 1, comboBox)
    i += 1

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to work with these combo-boxes, but I have several problems. It already starts with the fact that I can only use the last created combo-box with the following command:

```
comboBox.activated[str].connect(do_something)
```

I need to know the following things:

- How to connect signals for all the combo-boxes?
- How to get the index of the selected combo-box?
- How to get the index of the selected combo-box option after it was chosen?

Comment: You can keep all ComboBoxes on list to have access to all - `combobox_list.append(comboBox)`. You can assign own variables to comboBox ie. `comboBox.my_index = i`. BTW: more pythonic way `for i, j in enumerate(names):`

Comment: @furas Thank you! That helps me a little bit. `combobox_list[n_box].currentIndexChanged.connect(do_something)` But how to get the index of the combobox_list after it was clicked?

Comment: In `do_something()` you can get widget directly - `widget = event.sender()` and you don't need its index. Now you can do ie. `widget.addItem("Other Option")`, `print(widget.my_index)`, or get selected option `widget.currentText()`, etc. If you need index and you didn't create `comboBox.my_index` then you can try standard list functions like `combobox_list.index(widget)` or `if widget in combobox_list`.

Comment: I tried your code and it seems it work different when you don't create classes like in http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/widgets2/

Comment: You have to use `widget = app.sender()` inside `do_something` to get widget. And PyQt calls `do_something(index)` with argument `index` - so you have index of selected option.

Comment: @furas Unfortunately I don't get it :-/ I can return the index of the clicked element in a combobox, which works fine with this one in a for loop: `combobox_list[n_box].currentIndexChanged.connect(do_somethin‌​g)` but I can't return which actually oh them comboboxes was clicked. And I have to return both: index of combobox element and from which combobox it comes. Thank you for the further tips, I will try them later

Comment: To get widget use `widget = app.sender()`. To get its index on list use `combobox_list.index(widget)` or use own variable like `comboBox.my_index = i` and then `i = widget.my_index`

Comment: See working code: http://pastebin.com/96rpzf5m

Comment: @furas. Why don't you just post a proper answer?

Comment: @ekhumoro I was working with code and I forgot about question :) But you are right - I will add my code as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Description below code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

########################## Create table ##############################

tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 200, 250, 300))
tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
tableWidget.setRowCount(9)
tableWidget.show()

################# Create tablecontent & comboboxes ###################

def dosomething(index):
    widget = app.sender()
    print('widget object:', widget)
    print('widget myname:', widget.my_name)
    print('widget index:', combo_list.index(widget))
    print('option index:', index)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

names = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4']
combo_option_list = ["Choose...", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]

combo_list = []

for i, name in enumerate(names):

    tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(name))

    combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    combobox.addItems(combo_option_list)
    combobox.my_name = name + ' (i=' + str(i) + ')'
    combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(dosomething)

    combo_list.append(combobox)

    tableWidget.setCellWidget(i, 1, combobox)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Inside `dosomething` you can use `app.sender()` to get widget which was clicked - and then you can use it to do something with this widget.

PyQt executes `dosomething` with argument - it is index of selected option in combobox.

To get index of `widget` in `combo_list` you can use standard list method `combo_list.index(widget)`

But you can also create own variable in combobox (ie. `my_name`) to keep index or other value

```
combobox.my_name = some_value
```

and later you can get in `dosomething`

```
value = widget.my_name
```

---

BTW:

instead of `addItem(one_option)` and `for` loop you can use `addItems(option_list)`

You can use `enumerate(names)` and you will not need `i = 0` and `i += 1`

```
for i, j in enumerate(names):
```

You can create `combo_option_list` before `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part here is getting the index of the combo-box within the table, because a cell-widget cannot know its own index. One way to solve this is to use the `indexAt()` method of the table, which can get an index from a `QPoint`. A cell-widget *does* know its own position relative to its parent, so this can be passed to `indexAt()` to get its index within the table.

Below is a simple demo that shows how to connect up the signals and get all the information that you want:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(9, 2, self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        names = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4']
        options = ["Choose...", "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
        for index, name in enumerate(names):
            self.table.setItem(index, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(name))
            comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            comboBox.activated.connect(self.comboActivated)
            comboBox.addItems(options)
            self.table.setCellWidget(index, 1, comboBox)

    def comboActivated(self, option):
        combo = self.sender()
        print('option: %s, "%s"' % (option, combo.itemText(option)))
        index = self.table.indexAt(combo.pos())
        print('row: %s, column: %s' % (index.row(), index.column()))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 200, 300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```